# Why does this SQL code require "country_code" to run instead of just "code?"

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm taking a practice SQL course, and I'm trying to understand why the following code only works if I run it the exact way that I am going to copy/paste it for you. Specifically, I want to know why "country_code" is required in my WHERE clause rather than just "code." If you look at my subquery, you will see that I SELECTED "code" from the first two tables. The column "country_code" is only relevant after the EXCEPT clause, as I specifically want the codes that are NOT listed in the populations' table's "country_codes." Shouldn't it follow that my WHERE clause up top needs to have "code" in it? When I change it to "code," it doesn't work. It only accepts "country_code"

In fact, if I only run the subquery by itself, the only column that shows up is the "code" column anyway, and that is what I'm searching from.

```
SELECT name
FROM cities AS c1
WHERE country_code IN
    (SELECT e.code
    FROM economies AS e
    UNION
    SELECT c2.code
    FROM currencies AS c2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT p.country_code
    FROM populations AS p
    ORDER BY code);
```

Comment: Because the field `country_code` is in table `cities` and `code` is not.

Comment: What are the columns of the `cities` table? That is what the `WHERE` clause is relative to

Comment: I got it. Yes @AdrianKlaver the column in the cities table is country_code, not code. I checked that earlier, but I guess I had a brain fart and thought that country_code was only in the populations table.

Answer (score 0):

where is use for filter some data from the tabel which is after the key word 'FROM'.
your sql can write as this

```
SELECT name
FROM cities AS c1
WHERE c1.country_code IN
    (SELECT e.code
    FROM economies AS e
    UNION
    SELECT c2.code
    FROM currencies AS c2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT p.country_code
    FROM populations AS p
    ORDER BY code);
```

Also follow is an example help understand

```
SELECT name
    FROM cities AS c1
    WHERE c1.country_code IN ('code1','code2','code3')
```